# Getting package name in custom spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am using a custom spinner library, [Material Spinner](https://github.com/jaredrummler/Material-Spinner/issues). I have set adapter to the spinner as I want the font size to be different in the `getDropDownView`. I have three spinners out of which two just show the packagename. The middle spinner is working properly.

[image]

Everything is the same for all three spinners other than the array and the width. So why is the middle spinner. I can't figure out what the issue is.

**This is not a duplicate question**

One reason mentioned is that the `getView` method should be overridden. As can be seen below, it has been done. What I did find that in the case of the 1st and 3rd spinner the getView method or the getDropDownView method is not being called. I don't understand why.

`getItemCount`, `getItemId`, `getItem` methods are not needed. But when I had these methods also, the result did not change.

```
MaterialSpinner msDay = (MaterialSpinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fgenderage_ms_day);
    List dayList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fgenderage_day));
    msDay.setItems(new EnglishSpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), dayList));

    MaterialSpinner msMonth = (MaterialSpinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fgenderage_ms_month);
    List monthList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fgenderage_month));
    msMonth.setAdapter(new EnglishSpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), monthList));

    MaterialSpinner msYear = (MaterialSpinner) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fgenderage_ms_year);
    List yearList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fgenderage_year));
    msYear.setItems(new EnglishSpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), yearList));
```

The adapter:

```
public class EnglishSpinnerAdapter extends MaterialSpinnerAdapter{
private List list;
private Context ctx;

public EnglishSpinnerAdapter(Context context, List items) {
    super(context, items);
    ctx = context;
    list = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(ctx);
    textView.setText(list.get(position).toString());
    return textView;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(ctx);
    textView.setText(list.get(position).toString());
    return textView;
}
```

Comment: Are view definitions in XML layout exactly the same? (Except ID)

Comment: yes. Only width is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
 msDay.setItem(new EnglishSpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), dayList));
```

to this

```
 msDay.setAdapter(new EnglishSpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), dayList));
```

Comment: Oh...this is really silly. It did not show an error.

Comment: Your welcome =) . If it is solved your problem please accept answer.